# Method chaining with the same method

Tags: php

```
$db->SELECT("tablename")->WHERE()
$db->update("tablename")->WHERE()
Etc..
```

How can I determine in the WHERE method what method that was called first? I want to use the same WHERE method on both SELECT, update and delete.

Is it Even possible? Thanks!

Comment: You're missing a tag saying which library/framework you're using.

Comment: What @Musa said.  I can show you how to code it but only if it's a library you made.  If it's something like Doctrine, then I suggest seeing their documentation.  You may be able to clone $db and change the update etc..

Comment: $db->select("users")->where(array("username", "=", "username"));
$db->update("users", array("username" => "username"))->where(array("id", "=", "14"));

Ok, I guess my explaining is bad. I want to write the statements like above, and chain the where() method onto select and update.
Problem is; how to determined if I used the select or update before where.

public function where() {
    if($this->select()) { 
        // save the where data in the select var. }
        elseif($this->update()) {
        // save the where data in the update var. }
}

But the code above is obviously not valid.

Comment: I dont using any framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that make not really sense to call a where clause more then one time.

If you build you own system you should take a look at Doctrine for example. Here are functions like

```
where
andWhere
orWhere
```

So you can call **where** only one time but you can call the other functions more then one time and build statement.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Comment: Thank you. I not want to call the WHERE method twice on the SELECT. But if i use both the SELECT and the update on the same page. The problem is, if i use WHERE on SELECT and update i only manage to save the value from the last one. And i want to append the value from the WHERE method to the SELECT variable and to the update variable if i use the update method. Hope this make sense :)